# react-native-swipeout not working for android

Tags: react-native, swipe, react-navigation

It's working for ios but some it's not working for Android. I am using `tab navigation` and `FlatList`. Inside `FlatList` I am using `Swipeout`. Below code for example.

```
const renderItem =()=>{
  return (
    <Swipeout {...swipeAction(index,item, 'REMOVE ITEM',) }>
        <View>
            <Text>Swipe me left</Text>
        </View>
    </Swipeout>
  )
}
const list= <FlatList renderItem={renderItem} />

TabNavigator({
  itemList: { screen: list },
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add an extra parameter for tab navigator.`swipeEnabled: false`

```
const renderItem =()=>{
 return (
   <Swipeout {...swipeAction(index,item, 'REMOVE ITEM',) }>
    <View>
        <Text>Swipe me left</Text>
    </View>
   </Swipeout>
 )
}
const list = <FlatList renderItem={renderItem} />
TabNavigator({
  itemList: { screen: list },
  navigationOptions: {
  header: null,
  swipeEnabled: false,        
 }
})
```